# Any director or scientist watching our community questions for their upcoming project ideas?

Tags: discussion

People here would post a lot of questions, actually i would say ideas. They include,

- A lot of science based Fiction kind of situations and solutions(implying answer for the question)
- Ideas of unbelievable weapons.
- About aliens and other planets
  etc....

so I was wondering that, If any of the hollywood director, any director for that matter, out there is watching this site for his upcoming science based fiction movie ideas?

or

Any of the scientist is watching this questions and started researching towards it?

Would that be happening? I thought that because people here are intelligent enough to post such wonderful ideas so far.

Comment: I do not believe this is on topic for meta - or really any SE site. Are you asking if the site has movie directors and scientists (of any variety?) as members? I do believe that we have a few physicists and biologists who joined from the biology and physics SE sites.

Comment: The person who asked [this question](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21580/what-is-the-viability-of-a-planet-rotating-on-two-axes) claims to be a scriptwriter.

Comment: I think you confused director with dictator.

Answer (score 4):

Most writers will tell you that *ideas* are the easy part; it's all the time, sweat, late nights, discarded drafts, and caffeine that go into the final work that *really* take all the time and effort.  Further, while we are a clever and creative bunch, we're not the only people with interesting ideas; if you pursue writing/film-making you probably already have way more than you can use.

So "stealing" ideas isn't too attractive, and even if somebody did, your idea would become a tiny fraction of the overall work.  Sure it'd be nice for them to acknowledge you if that happens, but you wouldn't really be in a position to force the issue.  You can't copyright ideas, only concrete implementations of those ideas -- books, scripts, songs, videos, etc.

Personally, one of the things I love about this site is the open sharing.  We're here to help each other *and* the people who find our posts later.  If somebody takes an idea I threw out and builds something awesome from it, that's a *win* to me.

Answer (score 3):

Any such person would be in an *interesting* legal position when it comes to multi-million-dollar hollywood projects. Have you checked the [copyright terms](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode) of this site? Hollywood investors want exclusive rights to their material, and CC prevents that.

Comment: Actually the CC protects our *text*, not our ideas. Any such person can still use our ideas to write a script and they will own that exclusively.

Comment: But "based on a CC text" means that somebody else could use the same idea for a rival film. Do merchandise based on it.

Comment: Disney creates movies based on Grimm Brother's fairy tales. Since Grimm Brother's fairy tales are public domain, everyone else can do that, too. Yet Disney seems to have no problem with that.